# In Grails, how can I override the AuditlLogEvent domain class from Audit-Logging plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, audit-logging

I tried to create a domain subclass (different package) but migration plugin returned ambiguous class exception.

I tried creating a copy of that domain class (same package) but compiler returned duplicate class error.

How to override the AuditLogEvent class properly? Should I create a customized copy of that plugin?

Answer (score 0):

We're working on a bootstrap integration of the AuditLogEvent class, so everyone got it in their project instead of the plugin integrated one. You can create it from the source branch for testing:

https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/tree/feature_1.x/externalizeALE1.x

When using this 1.0.6-SNAPSHOT version in your project, you must perform "grails audit-quickstart" to create the AuditLogEvent domain class in your project. It's registered in Config.groovy. See audit-test test application setup how it works.

Would be great if you can feedback in https://github.com/robertoschwald/grails-audit-logging-plugin/issues/13